# Pandas Dataframe replace string value based on condition AND using original value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
        YEAR  MONTH  DAY_OF_MONTH  DAY_OF_WEEK ORIGIN_CITY_NAME ORIGIN_STATE_ABR DEST_CITY_NAME DEST_STATE_ABR DEP_TIME DEP_DELAY_NEW ARR_TIME ARR_DELAY_NEW CANCELLED AIR_TIME
0       2020      1             1            3          Ontario               CA  San Francisco             CA     1851            41     2053            68         0       74
1       2020      1             1            3          Ontario               CA  San Francisco             CA     1146             0     1318             0         0       71
2       2020      1             1            3          Ontario               CA       San Jose             CA     2016             0     2124             0         0       57
3       2020      1             1            3          Ontario               CA       San Jose             CA     1350            10     1505            10         0       63
4       2020      1             1            3          Ontario               CA       San Jose             CA      916             1     1023             0         0       57
...      ...    ...           ...          ...              ...              ...            ...            ...      ...           ...      ...           ...       ...      ...
607341  2020      1            16            4         Portland               ME       New York             NY      554             0      846            65         0       57
607342  2020      1            17            5         Portland               ME       New York             NY      633            33      804            23         0       69
607343  2020      1            18            6         Portland               ME       New York             NY      657             0      810             0         0       55
607344  2020      1            19            7         Portland               ME       New York             NY      705             5      921            39         0       54
607345  2020      1            20            1         Portland               ME       New York             NY      628             0      741             0         0       52
```

I am trying to modify columns `DEP_TIME` and `ARR_TIME` so that they have the format *hh:mm*. All values should be treated as strings. There are also `null` values present in some rows that need to be accounted for. Performance is also of consideration (albeit secondary in relation to solving the actual problem) since I need to change about 10M records total.

The challenge in this problem to me is figuring out how to modify these values iteratively based on a condition **while also having access to the original value when replacing it**. I simply could not find a solution for that specific problem elsewhere. Most problems are using a *known* constant to replace.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/42529454/4037715

Comment: In this case I would have to convert the targeted strings to a time object and back to string again since I want the format hh:mm in my dataframe. Seems complicated